# How can i save already done UV maps when merging two objects

Tags: uv

I have two objects which have already unwrapped UV's and I wont to merge them
in to one object but when I do that I lose UV's map from one object, so is there a 
way to merge them with preserved UV's ?

Comment: they should not lose their UV map

Comment: https://youtu.be/jhGJt4jEFfk

Comment: could you please share your file (only these 2 objects)?

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/f93a7929258f4a1d91f58f01a86f0b8d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're using Blender Render but I've got the solution. First merge all the columns, then in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *UV Maps*, change the name of the UV map you're currently using, use the one you're using for the temple itself (it is called *UVMap*). Join everything, it works.

[image]

Comment: Yep that's it tnx